# How can I paint objects altogether like this?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

Consider:

[image]

How can I paint objects altogether like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter UV mode, and select "Project from View". Then add the texture image you want as usual.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Not a new answer, but I suggest mentioning that you JOIN all the copies of the object and then create a second UV map from the original so that you can use Project from View and then 'Paint' on all at once. Otherwise, each object needs to be selected for the paint to work and that will be painful.
Picture for illustration.
[image]

Comment: Great, I learn much from you.